# Multicore multiprocess performance issue on Linux ARM environment

Tags: linux, multi-core, arm, cpu-cache

I am developing a Linux application on 4-core ARM CPU.
There are two processes in the application and I allocated each process to the cpu like below.

- core1 : process1 (GUI)
- core2-4 : precess2 (Realtime application)

Without process1, process2 easily handle its process and there is nothing to worry about. But the problem is that when I run the process1, it has a huge impact on the performance of process2 and the process2 does not work properly at all.

What could be a reason for this?

**Additional info:**

- cpu2-4 is isolated with isolcpus=1-3
- I traced the threads of the whole system, I noticed that only when there is the process1, process2 wakes a lot of tasks called rcu_preempt on core1. These two processes don't share any memory though.
- I replaced the process1 with some other processes, and I found that a process rapidly writing a lot of data to an allocated memory affects process2. Just a process doing simple CPU work(like a while loop) does not affect.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken over all the CPUs, forcing the Linux kernel to preempt running processes
in order to run its own threads. The kernel then does not distinguish between the
CPUs and can preempt CPU1 equally well as any other CPU.
The more activity that happens in the computer, the kernel will need to preempt
even more, again, undiscriminating between CPUs.

In addition, CPU is not everything, and a computer's architecture may have more
implicit bottlenecks. Some of them are memory banks, where concurrent access
to a bank depends on the number of channels to that bank. Then there are the
computer's memory bus, the disk cache, the disk itself etc.

You may find some more hints about truly running a real-time process in the article
[How to run real-time application in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375904/how-to-run-real-time-application-in-linux)
However, it's your actual hardware that determines what will work better or worse.

Comment: Process on the CPU1 is not that much so the kernel tasks are working properly. And actually no kernel threads preempt threads on the CPU2-4. 
I think it's a memory/cache related issue too but I don't know how to investigate any further. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: `rcu_preempt` is a preemption threads whose task is to liberate memory items. To investigate further, read my link and the links it contains.

Comment: The contents are all about how to reduce latency when there is only a real-time application running. There is no discussion about memory management stuff between real time application and other applications, which is an issue here. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: The subject is vast enough that every such document can only point to the next item that needs to researched, if you wish to fully understand. The main point here is that having a real-time app in a computer that is used for other purposes needs more knowledge, and that assigning CPUs isn't the best solution. Most real-time apps work on priority and leave the kernel to decide. Interfering with the kernel by manual assignment of resources usually leads to the opposite of what's intended.